# Nifi and Postgresql with certificate: how to set client certificate and key?

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, certificate, apache-nifi

I have a NIFI image running in openshift and a postgres in the cloud "owned" by another department.

**They sent to us a certificate(".crt") and a key(".key"), since the log-in is made trough client certificate, instead of username and password. I have succeeded to log-in in pgAdmin 4, but not to connect the NIFI to the Postgres with certificate and key.**

I have uploaded the certificate and the key to the image (using a secret and mounting it) so if I go to the pod terminal I can access it.

But, when I pass to a DBCPConnectionPoll service the connection string bellow and activates an ExecuteSQL processor, I receive an exception that the certificate is not valid, as follows:

```
ERROR
ExecuteSQL[id=...] Unable to execute SQL query <...>;
due to java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create a PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate).
No FlowFile to route to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create a PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate)
```

**I have tried to pass the certificate in two ways to the DBCPConnectionPoll service:**

1) as parameters in the connection string ("database connection url" property:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:<port>/<username>?user=<username>&sslTrue&sslcert=/etc/.../mycerts/mycert.der&sslkey=/etc/.../mycerts/mykey.key.pk8
```

2) adding properties in the service (+ button and the just parameter name and the path as the value) and just passing this as url:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:<port>/<username>
```

Both seems to work generally speaking, since I can connect to another postgres I have which not requires ssl certification.

Some considerations:

1) **My assumption** here is that the connection string in the NIFI does not know to read properly the file path for the certificate and key.

2) I have converted the certificates a bunch of times to different types that java can receive in order to see if that was the problem, but I still receive the same exception. So it seems that the connection pool just does not "achieve" the files at all. Nevertheless, if some one has a say in this topic, it can be handy, after the main problem is solved. So appreciate some tips here as well.

3) I have also read the NIFI source code and it seems that NIFI uses normally JDBC classes to create the connection pool, so a connection string as I passed would have worked in java code, but somehow doesn't work in NIFI (which is written in java).

4) The jdbc driver and everything else is configured properly, since I can work with a non-secure postgres in NIFI.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker found the 'simple solution' to the problem I asked and I would like to share so it can help others.

What was missing was the property sslmode = require. After including that, the service worked perfectly. Actually, I am not sure why it didn't work with sslmode = prefer, since it is what my pgadmin is using for the same database and there it works perfectly. It seems like we must 'force' nifi to use ssl in this case - see documentation here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html.

Moreover, some insights:

1. It worked with certificate in '.der' and key in '.pk8' formats (didn't have to use trust-store and key-store as needed in other services).
2. One can add in the 'plus' button the properties and give them the right name as we would do in java code, instead of concatenating every property in the connection string (see second option in the question above).

Make it helps others as well.

Comment: Yerachmiel Feltzman, could you please share how finally should look the connection string inside the Control Service ? I'm also facing such issue but with MySql database and it doesn't work. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Andrzej. I don't have access to the connection string  right now to help you. Maybe in a week or two. Did you try to set the ssl mode to be REQUIRED?